# Decrypting armour engrams with different classes

Tags: destiny

Can you decrypt armour engrams with different classes for different rewards?

For example, if I earn a blue engram with a level 30 hunter, put it in the vault, and decrypt the engram with a level 20 warlock, will the item be for a warlock?

If possible, this could be a good way of gaining gear with light for new characters at level 20.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing about rare armour engrams or less - I know that legendary ones decrypt to a random class, as it says in the item description. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the *level* of the decrypted item is based on the level of the character that decrypts it - though I'm not sure how this works post-20 levels.

Comment: @Amadeus9 they are rare level 20 sets

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes!

I did this not too long ago, just last week actually. I farmed 25 strikes on my 31 warlock for an exotic bounty. All armor engrams (and weapon engrams to level the cryptarch) went into the vault. Then I went onto my level 22 hunter (who needed legs and helmet) and decrypted all of them. Aside from the random Motes of Light and Strange Coins, it decrypted into hunter gear.

Comment: You should note that if a blue engram decrypts into a legendary then it could be for a different class.

Comment: @Tyler The OP already mentioned that he is aware of that. Therefore I did not see a reason to mention it.

Comment: Ok. I didn't notice that comment at first.

Comment: I was also able to reproduce  this issue.

Comment: I do this all the time to get my alts their armor upgrade materials (eg - Plasteel Plating).